# Changing value of table in object changes the value for all objects. How do I get it to only change it for the specific object?

Tags: lua

I'm not too knowledgeable on objects in Lua so bear with me.
Sample Code:

```
Colors = {  
        primary = "BF2626",   
        primaryGradient = {"CC2929", "B32424"}
        }

function Colors:new(o)
  o = o or {}
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
end

function Colors:setPrimaryGradient()
  self.primaryGradient[1] ="Changed"
end

function Colors:setPrimary()
  self.primary ="00FF00"
end

a =Colors:new()
b =Colors:new()

b:setPrimaryGradient()
b:setPrimary()

print(a.primaryGradient[1])
print(b.primaryGradient[1])
print(a.primary)
print(b.primary)
```

Output:

```
Changed
Changed
BF2626
00FF00
```

What am I doing wrong?
Why does the variable *primary* keep its value for each object but the tables don't?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `new` function sets up a metatable for the empty table. This metatable has functions *and* internal data. It also sets up an `__index` metamethod. That's important.

Your `setPrimaryGradient` method takes `self` as an implicit parameter. In this case, `self` is the new table that was created in `new`. Your problem is here:

`self.primaryGradient[1]` is not a single construct. It is *two separate operations*. Let's write it out how Lua uses it: `self["primaryGradient"][1]`. See the problem?

The first part, `self["primaryGradient"]` will check the `self` table and get it's `primaryGradient` member. The problem is that because `self` has an `__index` metamethod, and there is no `primaryGradient` member in `self` directly, it will therefore use the `__index` metamethod directly. So it will get the `primaryGradient` *from the metatable*. A metatable that is *shared*.

The `[1]` part will then be executed on the metatable's member, and a value will be stored in the first element of the `primaryGradient` *from the metatable*.

The reason why `setPrimary` doesn't exhibit the same problem is quite simple. `self.primary` is one operation. Because it's a table access followed by an assignment operation, Lua will not use the `__index` metamethod. It will instead use the `__newindex` metamethod. Since you didn't define one for `self`'s metatable, it will use the default logic: create a new member in `self` and set its value.

The reason `setPrimaryGradient` doesn't use `__newindex` is because it does. Just not for the access to `self`. It uses `__newindex` on the access to `self["primaryGradient"]`; only the *last* table access gets the `__newindex` call.

If you want to initialize your types with some default values that you can then modify, you need to *copy* those values. You can't just reference global ones sometimes. Well, you could, but it would be a big pain to set up.

Comment: That makes sense.
Thanks Nicol!

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be easily fixed in this way:

```
Colors = {  
        primary = "BF2626",   
        primaryGradient = {"CC2929", "B32424"}
        }
Colors.primaryGradient.__index = Colors.primaryGradient

function Colors:new(o)
  o = o or {primaryGradient = setmetatable({}, self.primaryGradient)}
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
end
```